# How can I stream a set of mp3 files in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, audio-streaming

I have several mp3 files in a directory that I want to stream one after the other such that a browser would (a) start playing the audio immediately and continue to play through all of the mp3s until I close the response stream.  (The intent is an endpoint that functions like a playlist mp3 stream.)

Here is my code:

```
import express from 'express';

const app = express();

function startServer() {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
  });
}

app.get('/stream', (req, res) => {
  const mp3Files = fs.readdirSync('.').filter(file => file.endsWith('.mp3'));
  let i = 0;

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'audio/mpeg');
  res.set('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');

  function sendFile() {
    const mp3File = mp3Files[i];
    console.log(`processing ${mp3File}`);
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(mp3File);
    fileStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
      res.write(chunk);
    }).on('end', () => {
      i++;
      if (i < mp3Files.length) {
        sendFile();
      } else {
        res.end();
      }
    });
  }
  sendFile();
});

startServer();
```

I can confirm that all of the mp3 files are processed, but the browser only plays the audio from the first one.  To be clear, I'm not doing anything at all on the client side - I'm merely pointing Chrome to the express API endpoint.

I'm looking to get the same outcome as seen if I point Chrome to any other (working) streaming audio URL, such as https://audio1.maxi80.com.

Any thoughts as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What you have should theoretically work.... looking....

Comment: See example at [Combining Sequential Streams with Node.js and Express](https://barstool.engineering/combining-sequential-streams-with-node-js/).

Comment: If I remember right I believe this is because MP3 files have their own headers which include metadata such as bit rate, file length, etc. But when you to stream several MP3 files one after another the browser reads the header of the first MP3 file and expects the rest of the stream to correspond to that header. It doesn't expect another header (from the second file) to appear in the middle of the stream, which confuses the browser so it stops playing.

Comment: @selbie You mentioned that you think this should be working though so you might know better than I do. Do you have any thoughts regrading this?

Comment: @PCDSandwichMan - OP's code works "as-is" with minimal adjustments. I don't think ID3 tags contain a stream length hint. But I left that as a possibility in my answer below.

Comment: You’re missing some metadata expected with the chunk when you use transfer-encoding chunked. This `res.write(chunk);` should be updated to include the chunk size and some pre/post-ended CRLF’s. See an [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding#chunked_encoding).

Answer (score 2):

I got your code to work as is and it was successfully transitioning to the next song for a entire directory of mp3 files (50mb total). These 12 files were all ripped from the CD the same way. But a few things stick out to me.

Most important. You probably want a Content-Length header that's the sum of the file sizes being sent. I hacked this in:

```
  const mp3Files = fs.readdirSync('.').filter(file => file.endsWith('.mp3'));
  let i = 0;
  let contentLenght = 0;

  mp3Files.forEach(file => {
    contentLength += fs.statSync(file).size;
  });

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'audio/mpeg');
  res.setHeader('Content-Length', contentLength);
  res.set('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');
```

That had the effect of the browser's simple audio player showing a better estimate of the total stream time.  The progress bar was in a reasonable position instead of just keeping at the end.

[image]

Second thing I noticed is that there's no throttling of the read stream when the callback invokes `res.write`. When the client connected, 50MB of data was near instantly pushed into the write stream. You can hack in a console.log statement to print out `chunk.length` on each `data` callback to see what I mean.

I suppose the browser pulled it all down quickly since I was on localhost.  But if the client has limited buffer and is streaming at pace with the music, won't that put a lot of back pressure of bytes onto the node process?  Consider hooking the `drain` event on the response object and write into the response stream at the pace it wants. I could be mistaken, but there's no free lunch for buffering if the client isn't doing much buffering itself.

Final thing. I don't know the files you are working with, but if any of the ID3 headers contain some sort of length hint, that might be confusing the browser client's player.  Hence, the Content-Length header inserted above should fix that. (Disclaimer: I don't think ID3 headers actually contain a length hint. I could be mistaken).

Comment: `Transfer-Encoding: chunk` is used so that’s why there was no `Content-Length` header. In this scenario the length of each chunk is supposed to be prepended to the chunk in hexadecimal format, followed by `\r\n` and then the chunk itself, followed by another carriage return line feed. Check out the [example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding#directives). That’s probably why there was no throttling applied as well.

Comment: This answer was helpful, but the final use case I'm working on uses dynamically-generated audio so I won't know the content up front (meaning I can't use a content-length header).  The point you made about the ID3 headers got me to the core of my original problem, however:  not all of my test mp3s were of the same bitrate, sampling or even channel counts.  When I made them all the same through ffmpeg, the browser plays them sequentially as desired.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Scott - interesting. Most MP3 players know how to handle variable bitrate mp3 files, so it's weird it couldn't handle a VBR stream.  In any case, I'm glad you got it working. mp3 streaming is fun stuff.